# React: Passing a template literal as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

I have a  component that has a border: string prop (typescript). The way I want to pass in this prop is like below:

```
<Button border={`'1px solid' ${borderColor}`} />
```

Where ${borderColor} is a state variable. My prop is working when hard-coding the border, like this:

```
<Button border="1px solid black" />
```

But how can I make it work when mixing a string/state variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this code sample, you can remove the quotes around `1px solid` and it should work for you. With template strings, the tick marks (`) are the only string wrappers you need!

Here is a demo showing you how it works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-glitter-sbjrqf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
<Button border={`1px solid ${borderColor}`} />
```

You can read more about template literals here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals